How powerful is this 'non-deterministic' reduction?
Let us define NP.NP as a class of problems that non-deterministically reduces to 3SAT.

Within the scope of this post, assume non-deterministic reduction is a non-deterministic Turing machine (or algorithm) that computes (in polytime) the function associated with the reduction.

This is inspired by BP.NP; a class of problems with polytime probabilistic reduction to 3SAT.
I see $NP.NP$ is contained in polynomial hierarchy $\Sigma_2 = NP^{NP}$.
(I) Can this upper bound be improved?
(II) Is NP.NP comparable to $P^{NP}$? Or,
(III) NP.NP = NP?
My approach: I am trying to see if I can rule out the containment of co-NP in NP.NP. I don't have a rigorous way to resolve this. Any help or pointer would be much appreciated.

The idea of a non-deterministic reduction in this post is inspired by the np-reduction on page 10 (first paragraph) of the reference:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0308021
It is similar to many-one reduction (like Karp), but the reduction function is polytime computable by a Non-deterministic machine.

You did not actually define what you mean by “nondeterministic reduction”.

@EmilJeřábek, Point. I have added a definition of non-deterministic reduction.

It’s not clear to me whether the “function” can be multivalued, or whether the nondeterministic machine is required to always output the same value. But either way, NP is clearly closed under such reductions.

Which type of reduction?  many-one reduction?  Turing reduction?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction

@D.W., your concern is valid. It is many-one. I am using 'non-deterministic reduction' in the same sense as mentioned on page 10 (first paragraph) of the below paper.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0308021

The paper does not define the notion either. They just use it as an informal description of one example.

FWIW, what they use does not look like a "reduction function", but the $\exists$ operator combined with a many-one reduction. NP is certainly closed under such things. That's the whole point of Lemma 5 after all: whatever exactly "nondeterministic reduction" might mean in the minds of the authors, NP is closed under it.

That is, what the paper does has the following form: $L\le L'$ if there is a polytime function $f(x,y)$ and a polynomial $p$ such that $x\in L\iff\exists y,\bigl(|y|\le p(|x|)\land f(x,y)\in L'\bigr)$.
